# Multer package problem in my Node.js and React.js app

Tags: typescript, mern, multer

My problem is with the Multer-package installed with npm, and I am trying to upload a single img-file from the frontend to the backend, but the img- simply does not end up in that folder as I specified in the backend .diskStorage()-destination, but Insted it turns up as a `blob:https://sitename.netlify.app/303d0c13-e0fc-4d...etcrandomnumbers`
in the browser logs.

I am able to update all the other fields, and I have not included them here.

I have tried making a diskStorage like so:

```
import multer from 'multer';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')); // I have created this folder in the rootfolder
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
      cb(null, Date.now() + ext);
    }
  });
  
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

And the route:

```
router.put("/profile/update", upload.single('img'), async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const user = await updateUser(req);

  if (user) {
    if (.....
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
export const updateUser = async (data: Request) => {
  try {

    // data.file contains the uploaded image file
    const imgPath = data.body.img;

    const insert = {
      name: data.body.name,
      address: data.body.address,
      img: imgPath,
    };

    if (data.body.name) insert.name = data.body.name;
    if (data.body.address) insert.address = data.body.address;
    if (data.body.img) insert.img = data.body.img;

    
    if (insert) {
        const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: data.body._id }, insert, {
          new: true,
        }) 
        if (!user) {
          return { error: "User not found" };
        }
        return { error: null, data: user };
      } else {
        return { error: "No data to update" };
      }
  } catch (error: unknown) {
   console.log......
  }
};
```

In the model, the field "img" is specified like this:

```
img: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  }
```

//Frontend-component

```
``const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { id, value } = event.target;
    const fileInput = document.getElementById("img") as HTMLInputElement;
`
    if (
      id.startsWith("img") &&
      fileInput &&
      fileInput.files &&
      fileInput.files.length > 0
    ) {
      const file = fileInput.files[0];
      if (file) {
        setUser((prevUser: UserProfile | null) => ({
          ...prevUser!,
          img: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        }));
      }
      return;

`const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();`

      if (user) {
        const updatedData = {
          _id: user._id,
          img: user.img,
         /*other fields*/
        };

        const response = await updateUser(updatedData);
        if (response.error) {
          setError("Failed to update user data");
        } else 
  };


 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} **encType="multipart/form-data"**>
        

          <label>Ändra profilbild:</label>
          <input
            id=**"img"**
            type="file"
            placeholder={user.img}
            onChange={handleChange}
          ></input>

        `
```